# Jenkins " 'gradlew.bat' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. "

Tags: jenkins, gradle, jenkins-pipeline, pipeline, wrapper

I'm trying to build my project by using a scripted pipeline on Jenkins.

```
def getOperatingSystem() {
    if (isUnix()) {
        return 'UNIX'
    } else {
        return 'BAT'
    }
}

pipeline {
    agent any

    environment {
        OS = getOperatingSystem()
    }

    stages {
        stage('Checkout git repository') {
            steps {
                git branch: 'master', credentialsId: 'repo-credential-id', url: 'https://britop@bitbucket.org/mei-isep/odsoft-22-23-nmb-g303.git'
            }
        }

        stage('Build project for Linux') {
            when { expression { env.OS == 'UNIX' }}
            steps {
                //change execution path
                dir('odsoft-22-23-nmb-g303/') {
                    sh './gradlew clean build'
                }
            }
        }

        stage('Build project for Windows') {
            when { expression { env.OS == 'BAT' }}
            steps {
                //change execution path
                dir('odsoft-22-23-nmb-g303/') {
                    bat './gradlew.bat clean build'
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

When I run my pipeline I get the error that is on the title.

I tried the command `gradle wrapper` in order to generate the bat file, but only the following files were generated:

- gradle-wrapper.jar
- gradle-wrapper.properties

How can I generate the necessary files?

Comment: The error told you it failed to find `gradlew.bat` from folder `odsoft-22-23-nmb-g303`. you can add `bat dir` to list the items in `odsoft-22-23-nmb-g303`

Comment: Try hardcoding the full path for the `.bat` file. If that works, then you know the issue is with Jenkins being unable to find the file.